# p:cellEditor in p:dataTable not working consistently

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I wanted to create an editable table with JSF/PrimeFaces. Here is one column of the `<p:dataTable>` row:

```
<p:column>
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{onesubquestion.text.value}"/>
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="#{onesubquestion.text.value}" style="width:96%"/>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

It worked well for most of table cells, but it did not work for some, e.g, click on the text of the cell and the input field did not show up and there were no error messages.

Any suggestions of hints are appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Did I add the correct image?

Comment: Thank you Tiny. That is the correct image. This image shows an example. For the question 4, it works, but for question 5, when clicking on the text, the input field does not show up.